# How to remove the nth element from a tuple?

Tags: algorithm, templates, c++17, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

I'm trying to write a function that creates a new `std::tuple` from an existing one, with skipping the element on a given index. In example:

I have a tuple **`t`** defined as below:

```
constexpr auto t = std::tuple(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

And I want to copy it to another tuple. However, I want to skip the **nth** element. Let's say that in this case, the **nth** element I want to skip is 3 (this would mean that I want to skip the element with the index 2). This would result in a new tuple defined as:

```
std::tuple(1, 2, 4);
```

This is the closest I got until now:

```
template<std::size_t N, typename T, std::size_t ... is>
constexpr auto fun(T&& tp, std::index_sequence<is...>&& i) noexcept {
    return std::tuple((is != N ? std::get<is>(tp) : 0) ...);
}

template<std::size_t N, std::size_t... elems>
constexpr auto fun2() noexcept {
    constexpr auto t = std::tuple(elems...);
    return fun<N>(std::forward_as_tuple(elems...), std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(elems)>());
}
```

However, instead of removing the **nth** element, I set it to 0.

Ideally, I would change the return argument in the function `fun()` to create a new tuple using multiple temporary tuples:

```
return std::tuple_cat((is != N ? std::tuple(std::get<is>(tp)) : std::tuple()) ...);
```

However, the issue with this is that the ternary operator has to have matching types on both sides.

Another approach I tried was based on recursion:

```
template<std::size_t N, std::size_t head, std::size_t... tail>
constexpr auto fun3() noexcept {
    if constexpr(!sizeof...(tail))
        return std::tuple(head);

    if constexpr(sizeof...(tail) - 1 == N)
        return std::tuple_cat(fun3<N, tail...>());

    if constexpr(sizeof...(tail) - 1 != N)
        return std::tuple_cat(std::tuple(head), fun3<N, tail...>());
}
```

However, that was even more unsuccessful. In this case, if `N` is equal to 0, the **nth** element (which is the first element here as well) will still be used in the new tuple. Also, this won't even compile, because there's an issue with the second statement:

```
if constexpr(sizeof...(tail) - 1 == N)
```

What am I missing here? How can I copy a tuple and skip one of its elements during the copy?

I'm using C++17, and I need the function to be evaluated during compile-time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about

```
return std::tuple_cat( foo<is, N>::func(std::get<is>(tp)) ...);
```

where `foo` is a struct with specialization as follows?

```
template <std::size_t, std::size_t>
struct foo
 {
   template <typename T>
   static auto func (T const & t)
    { return std::make_tuple(t); } 
 }

template <std::size_t N>
struct foo<N, N>
 {
   template <typename T>
   static std::tuple<> func (T const &)
    { return {}; } 
 }
```

(caution: code not tested).

This is almost your ternary operator idea but without the problem of matching the types in both sides: only the right type is instantiated.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution would be to create two index sequences that refer to the before and after parts of the tuple.

```
template<std::size_t nth, std::size_t... Head, std::size_t... Tail, typename... Types>
constexpr auto remove_nth_element_impl(std::index_sequence<Head...>, std::index_sequence<Tail...>, std::tuple<Types...> const& tup) {
    return std::tuple{
        std::get<Head>(tup)...,
        // We +1 to refer one element after the one removed 
        std::get<Tail + nth + 1>(tup)...
    };
}

template<std::size_t nth, typename... Types>
constexpr auto remove_nth_element(std::tuple<Types...> const& tup) {
    return remove_nth_element_impl<nth>(
        std::make_index_sequence<nth>(), // We -1 to drop one element 
        std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Types) - nth - 1>(),
        tup
    );
}
```

Here's a test for this function:

```
int main() {
    constexpr auto tup = std::tuple{1, 1.2, 'c'};
    constexpr auto tup2 = remove_nth_element<0>(tup);
    constexpr auto tup3 = remove_nth_element<2>(tup);
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(tup2), const std::tuple<double, char>>);
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(tup3), const std::tuple<int, double>>);
    return 0;
}
```

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/jjeVnA)

This solution has the advantages of not constructing intermediary tuples and not using `std::tuple_cat`, which both can be hard on compile times.

Answer (score 0):

Just a few minutes after posting the question, I found a workaround. It's not ideal, but hey:

```
template<std::size_t N, typename T, std::size_t ... is>
constexpr auto fun(T&& tp, std::index_sequence<is...>&& i) noexcept {
    return std::tuple((is < N ? std::get<is>(tp) : std::get<is+1>(tp)) ...);
}

template<std::size_t N, std::size_t... elems>
constexpr auto fun2() noexcept {
    constexpr auto t = std::tuple(elems...);
    return fun<N>(std::forward_as_tuple(elems...), std::make_index_sequence<sizeof... (elems) - 1>());
}
```

This way, we copy all of the elements prior to the **nth** element, and when we reach the **nth** element, we increase every next index for 1. We won't go out of range, since we pass the index_sequence that has 1 element less than the tuple that is passed.

I hope that this answer helps someone.

Comment: Uhmmm... works because you have a `std::tuple` with elements of the same type, so `std::get<is>(tp)` and `std::get<is+1>(tp)` are of the same type. This isn't true with a generic `std::tuple` and you get the same error with your ternary operator with `std::tuple_cat()` solution: ternary operator with different types. But, maybe, you can apply this solution from the point of view of indexes: `std::tuple( std::get<( is < N ? is : is+1 )>(tp) ) ...);`

Comment: Yes, I need it for a use case where I have the same type across all elements. But your solution is so much better, it works with a generic `std::tuple`!
Just a note; you miss another bracket after `std::get<(`

It should be `std::tuple((std::get<( is < N ? is : is+1 )>(tp) ) ...);`

Comment: Are you right: wrong brackets. Maybe you can remove: `std::tuple( std::get<( is < N ? is : is+1 )>(tp) ...);`. Anyway: if you have a tuple with all elements of the same type, why don't you use `std::array`?

Comment: Ah, I'm wrong again, sorry! I was doing something else with fold expressions, and started thinking that I need more brackets than I did.

About `std::array`, I think that I could've used them for what I'm trying to achieve. I'm not really sure why I didn't do it in the first place. It would make my life easier hahah. But this isn't too bad either. if I ever decide to extend the functionality or use tuples for something else, I'll have a decent base if nothing else.